# on.exit not working but onStop working in shiny to delete cached data using unlink

Tags: r, caching, shiny, temp

I am caching some data which I want to be removed when I refresh the app by clicking the refresh button in the browser window. `onStop()` deletes the data every time I refresh but when I use `on.exit()` I can see data being cached in `/tmp/Rtmp*/app_data_xyz*/` and more such `app_data_*` files keep on getting added but the older ones are not removed. Why do these have different behaviours and how can I use `on.exit()` for doing this cleanup successfully assuming I need to use `on.exit()` specifically. I read that `onStop()` waits for the server to exit but `on.exit()` won't. Does this have something to do with it ?

server.R with on.exit()

```
function(input, output, session) {
  cache_dir = tempfile(pattern = 'app_data_')
  on.exit(unlink(cache_dir, recursive = TRUE))
.
.
}
```

server.R with onStop()

```
function(input, output, session) {
  onStop(function() {
    cat("Doing application cleanup\n")
    unlink(cache_dir, recursive = TRUE)
  })
.
.
}
```

Comment: The fact that `on.exit` appears to not work when the `server` function exits is interesting, and something I suspect that the shiny-authors will need to answer.

Comment: Any update on this? I am curious because I  am looking for a good practice for shiny app development...